# How to remap keyboard keys

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create an application that changes the value of the button that has been pressed.
Example: If the C button on the keyboard has been pressed then it should output the value of '7'. The buttons value should only change for as long as the application is running.

My code so far:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler( Form1_KeyDown );

    }

    void Form1_KeyDown( object sender, KeyEventArgs e )
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
        {


        }
    }
}
```

All help would greatly be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean globally in Windows or just within your application?

Comment: i want it to be globally but only for as long as the application is open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is in the scope of your application only, I would continue by making a hash map of keys to their binding.  (KeyCode => Your-Binding)

If you want an integer value like in your example, you'll have a map like:

```
Dictionary<KeyCode,Integer> keyMap = new Dictionary<KeyCode,Integer>();

void Form1_KeyDown( object sender, KeyEventArgs e )
{
    if(keyMap.ContainsKey(e.KeyCode) {
    int boundValue = keyMap[e.KeyCode];
    // continue with what you want to do here
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Onresolve, i want to make it globally, so for as long as the application is opened, that key will have the value that i set.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this works wonderfully for in scope of the application